# Showing the minimum number of characters needed for an input field

Tags: javascript, charactercount

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var maxLength=10;
function charLimit(el) {
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) return false;
    return true;
}

function characterCount(el) {
    var charCount = document.getElementById('charCount');
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) el.value = el.value.substring(0,maxLength);
    if (charCount) charCount.innerHTML = maxLength - el.value.length;
    return true;
}
</script>
```

together with this input field:

```
<input type="text" onKeyPress="return charLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return characterCount(this)" />
<span id="charCount">10</span>
```

As it is now, it's counting down the characters typed, from **10** to **0**. I want to add some code to it, where when the page is loaded, it will show **10 (enter 3 characters minimum)**, and when those three characters are entered, the text in the **( )** will be gone, and only the number will be left, i.e. **7**.

Also, if you erase the entered text, if character count is less than 3, the text in the **( )** to be shown again, i.e. something like this: **8 (enter 3 characters minimum)**

Or even better, if it can be made like this:

> 10 (0 characters entered out of 3 miniumum)
>   9 (1 characters entered out of 3 miniumum)
>   8 (2 characters entered out of 3 miniumum)
>   7

It doesn't need to be the current code I have, suggest other code if you have.

Comment: Have you tried making a solution yourself, or are you expecting a complete solution from us?

Comment: What you ask for isn't a "little tweak" as @Jam also said, but rather whole new "feature". You have to start by adding extra `<span>` with its own ID, beside the `charCount` span, then update its text every time, and hide/show it as required. Give this a try and update the question with your efforts and where you're stuck in case you'll still need help.

Comment: user1150525 made it happen ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because noone wrote an answer, I will write one. (Even if it doesn't look like you tried it yourself.)

```
function characterCount(el) {
    var charCount = document.getElementById('charCount');
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) el.value = el.value.substring(0,maxLength);
    if (charCount) charCount.innerHTML = maxLength - el.value.length;
    return true;
}
```

to

```
function characterCount(el) {
    var charCount = document.getElementById('charCount');
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) el.value = el.value.substring(0,maxLength);
    if (charCount) {
        if(el.value.length < 3) {
            charCount.innerHTML = (maxLength - el.value.length) + ' (' + (3 - el.value.length) + ' out of 3 characters minimum)';
        } else {
            charCount.innerHTML = maxLength - el.value.length;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this was quick and it's working as it should, thank you so much for the code. One question, though, is it possible to be made that ( ) text is shown on page load? Now it's shown when you start typing... Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was away for some minutes. You have to change <span id="charCount">10</span> to <span id="charCount">10 (0 out of 3 characters minimum)</span>

Comment: Hey, no need to apologise, you are the best :) It's working as I wanted, thank you so much, really appreciate it.